# char** в shared memory с++

Tags: c++, ipc

В коде ниже я пытаюсь создать массив строк в `shared memory`, ввести с клавиатуры первую строку, записать ее в массив в child-процесссе и вывести ее на экран в parent-процессе. При выводе строки в parent-процессе выводится мусор вместо того, что я ввел с клавиатуры. Что я делаю не так и как надо делать? **Обилие теоретической информации в ответе приветствуется.**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SHMSIZE 100
int main() {
   int shmid;
   char** shm;
   if(fork() == 0) {
      shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0);
      shm = (char**)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      char** s = (char**) shm;
      char buf [100];
      printf ("Enter string\n");
      scanf("%s", buf);
      s[0] = new char [strlen(buf)];
      s[0] = buf;
      printf ("<%s>\n",s[0]);
      shm [0] = s [0];
      printf ("Child wrote <%s>\n",shm[0]);
      shmdt(shm);
   }
   else {
      shmid = shmget(2009, SHMSIZE, 0666 | IPC_CREAT);
      shm = (char**)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
      wait(NULL);
      printf ("Parent reads %s\n",shm [0]) ;
      shmdt(shm);
      shmctl(shmid, IPC_RMID, NULL);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте попробую объяснить на пальцах.

Дело в том, что указатель — всего лишь число. Современные операционные системы обладают *виртуальной памятью*, и это самое число является всего-навсего номером байта в этой виртуальной памяти. У каждого процесса своё адресное пространство, и это означает, что память по адресу 0x1234567890abcdef у каждого процесса своя.

Отсюда следует важный вывод: передача указателей (которые, как мы помним, являются числами) между процессами имеет не так уж и много смысла, данные из адресного пространства одного процесса недоступны в другом процессе.

Исключение из этого — разделяемая память: область, которая является общей для нескольких процессов. Но эта самая общая область может вполне иметь разные адреса в этих процессах, поэтому в любом случае передача указателя между процессами не помогает. Смысл имеет лишь *смещение от начала разделяемой памяти*.

Для вашего случая, что делаете вы? Вы помещаете в разделяемую память указатель на другую, неразделяемую память (`s[0] = new char [strlen(buf)];`). Как это поможет? Никак, этот указатель в другом процессе ничего не означает.

---

Что делать? Ну, если вам нужно перебросить *одну* строку, то просто запишите её содержимое (не указатель!) в начало разделяемой памяти. Не забудьте проверить длину!

Если вам нужно перебросить массив строк, то вам придётся изобрести какой-нибудь формат сериализации. Например, такой:

1. В начале разделяемой памяти `size_t`-поле, в котором лежит количество строк (назовём его `N`).
2. Вслед за ним смещения в байтах от начала разделяемой памяти для каждой из строк, ровно `N` штук.
3. За ним идут строки, смещения которых определены в п. 2, завершающиеся `\0` для простоты.

Снова-таки, не забудьте убедиться, что вся конструкция влезает в разделяемый кусок памяти.

---

Запись должна выглядеть как-то так (не тестировал, нет юникса под рукой):

```
void* shm = ...;
size_t N = 10;
char** strings = ... ;
*(size_t*)shm = N;
size_t base_offset = sizeof(size_t) /* п. 1 */ + sizeof(size_t) * N /* п. 2 */;
size_t* toc = (size_t*)shm + 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    toc[i] = base_offset;
    strcpy(strings[i], (char*)shm + base_offset);
    base_offset += strlen(strings[i]) + 1 /* trailing zero */;
    // неоптимально: пробегает строки дважды
}
```

Ну и чтение:

```
void* shm = ...;
size_t N = *(size_t*)shm;
size_t* toc = (size_t*)shm + 1;
for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    printf("%s", (char*)shm + toc[i]);
}
```

---

Возможно, вам не следует заморачиваться с ручной сериализацией и строить велосипеды, а воспользоваться готовыми библиотеками для сериализации (их много, например, [Boost.Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html)). Или стоит, это уж вам решать.

Answer (score 0):

> Обилие теоретической информации в ответе приветствуется.

Вам несказанно повезло :)

Книга **"UNIX: взаимодействие процессов"** Уильяма Сивенса - есть [в онлайн доступе](http://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/148368/Stivens_-_UNIX__vzaimodeiistvie_processov.html).